# Getting Unable to verify your captcha response error when trying to log into github

Tags: github

I made a second github account from another email address and must have typed a different character than I was aware of when making my password.  I tried to reset the password and am getting the error listed in the title.  I went to the documentation page and did the tests present and passed both of them.  When I go to the reset page I don't get any type of capta, I just get a loading icon and eventualyl a green checkmark and when I click the "send password reset" email the error pops up and the loading icon resets.  I can still log in and out of my other account perfectly fine, but the new one is for some reason acting up.  Does anybody know why this is happening or know of a bug on their website that can be causing this?